# Getting initialization Error, when i am running Step definition file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Cucumber config setup :

I am receiving initialization error when i am running step definition file

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cucumber/deps/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/ConverterRegistry
```

Following dependency is used for build :

cucumber-picocontainer : 1.2.5
gherkin : 2.12.2
cucumber-reporting : 1.0
cucumber-jvm-dep : 1.0.5
cucumber-junit : 1.2.5
cucumber-jvm : 1.2.5
cucumber - java : 1.2.5

Runner file : cuccumberOptions
(features = "Features",
glue = "package name of step definition file"
)

Comment: Can you share the code snippet which causes the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  In this case, there's not enough information to reproduce your error.

Comment: @PirateX I am receiving error in initial config of cucumber setup. there is nothing in step definition file as such.                                                     This is feature file :  Feature: Login amazon page
Scenario: Free CRM Login Test Scenario

Given user is already on Login Page
When title of login page amazon
Then user enters username
Then user clicks on login button
And user is on home page

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/) on which dependencies you need to use Cucumber (and their recent version).

For instance, you don't need to import gherkin, as it's a transitive dependency.
In your case, you should only need cucumber-java, cucumber-junit, and cucumber-picocontainer. Make sure to use the same version for all of those dependencies.

Declare the version once:

```
<properties>
   <cucumber.version>4.3.1</cucumber.version>
</properties>
```

And use the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
    <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go Windows>preferences>Installed JREs and add path of jre and click on apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).